# Distortion Removal=Parallax Removal?

Tags: optics, distortion

So, as the title suggests: does distortion removal caused by lenses means that the parallax is also removed from the pictures?

Comment: What do you mean by "parallax"? Accordingly the commonly accepted definition, parallax is the difference in perspective between two viewpoints, for instance human eyes. In a (non-stereographic) photo you only have a single viewpoint so talking about parallax is not meaningful.

Comment: @JohannesD Yes that's correct. What I meant was if it is possible to view a number of scenes stereographically after the lens distortion is removed from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, these are unrelated. Distortion removal is a 2D mapping which moves pixels to remove barrel and pincushion distortion. Parallax correction requires multiple images or depth information for each pixel and is performed by completely different software algorithms.

Comment: This depth information is exactly what I am curious about. So, you say that it is not affected at all? From many projects -that involve 3D representation from pictures- that I have done, I get that it is not affected. I am just looking for the confirmation from someone that has this knowledge.

Comment: Ah, I think you are asking *if we perform distortion correction, do we get new depth info*. No, not really because the correction is 2D, so it does not generate new depth-info. If you have a depth-map though, then you would have to apply the same geometric processing to it too, so that it corresponds to the undistorted image.

Answer (score 1):

> if it is possible to view a number of scenes stereographically after the lens distortion is removed from them

Yes.

In theory all distortion correction does is undo some distortion a lens introduces because it is not an *ideal ( theoretcally perfect )* lens.  You will note this distortion is radially symmetrical and the effect is most notable in the curving of what should be straight lines in the image ( for rectilinear lenses ).

This should, in principle, make viewing two images as stereographic pairs *better* as the distorted images would be more likely to cause (minor) discrepancies from what the human vision system expects than the undistorted ones.

The correction should, again in theory, make it more accurate for a tool that estimates distance from stereographic pairs.  It is the distorted image that is more likely to cause problems.